# How do I use the -exists flag from "window" command?

Tags: mel

The maya manual does not describe how -exists flag in window command is used. I tried many ways of using it and it does not budge.

I've been fiddling and googling for 2 days, it wasn't going anywhere. I was only trying to detect if one of my window is opened or not.

Here's the test code I've got so far:

```
string $something = `window -title "name of the window" -widthHeight 200 150`;

columnLayout -adjustableColumn false;

button -label "detect this window" -command "dothis_1";



showWindow $something;



proc dothis_1()

{

   if (`window -ex $something` == true)

   {

      print "window detected!\n";

   }

   else

   {

     print "window detection failed!\n";

    }

}

//--------
```

So...I assumed I did something wrong somewhere or I simply misunderstood what -exists does? What did I do wrong and how do I detect whether my window is opened or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your procedure has a variable scope issue, where it doesn't know what `$something` is, because it's defined outside of it.

You could make your procedure accept an argument for a window name you want to check against, create your window, then pass its name to the button's command:

```
string $something = `window -title "name of the window" -widthHeight 200 150`;
columnLayout -adjustableColumn false;
button -label "detect this window" -command ("dothis_1 " + $something); // Pass window name to proc.
showWindow $something;


proc dothis_1(string $win) {
   if (`window -ex $win` == true) {
      print "window detected!\n";
   } else {
     print "window detection failed!\n";
   }
}
```

Alternatively you should be able to create a global variable so that it's accessible within the procedure too.

Although your use case is a bit weird. You can only click the button if the window exists!

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Your code works and I gotta say it's a bit complicated as for keeping track of the variables. I know where the problem is now. Also I just figured out not long after I post this, that you can actually specified the window id yourself, so that you know exactly what to query.
`window -title "name of window` -widthHeight 200 200 mywindowid_01;`
mywindowid_01 can be used to query by -exists flat. Thank you for the answer!

Comment: You can do it this way, though it produces an error if a window with that name already exists. So before creating it you can check if it exists beforehand, then use `deleteUI` to remove it. If you found this answer helpful you can upvote it, and if it resolved your issue you can also accept it to let people know that the question has been solved.